# React State Fields with Array of Objects

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I am having trouble getting this working with my React state. The set up below works and I can access the data I need, however I am looking to expand the 'questions' field so that it is an array of objects opposed to a single object.

```
this.state = { 
     ballots: [
        { 
        id: '2222' ,
        title: 'Test Ballot',
        questions: {title: 'Question 1', option: 'option 1' }
        }
    ]
    }
```

---

looking to have the state be like this.

```
this.state = { 
         ballots: [
            { 
            id: '2222' ,
            title: 'Test Ballot',
            questions: [{title: 'Question 1', options: ['option 1', 'option 2', 'option 3'] }, {title: 'Question 2', option: ['option 1', 'option 2', 'option 3']}]
            }
        ]
        }
```

I am mapping these value to another component as shown below.

```
return (
            <div className='ballot-page'>
                {this.state.ballots.map(
                    ({id, ...props}) => (
                        <BallotForm key={id} {...props} />
                    )
                )}
            </div>
        );
```

Would I need to map all the 'ballots' and then map again over each of the 'questions' to get all of the fields within it? Let me know if I can clarify this any better. Below is the BallotForm component.

```
const BallotForm = ({ title, questions }) => (
    <div className='ballot-form-page'>
        <div className='ballot-form'>
            <div className='ballot-title'>{title}</div>
            <span>{questions.title}</span>
            <form>
                <span>{questions.option}</span>
                <input type='checkbox'></input>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would I need to map all the 'ballots' and then map again over each of the 'questions' to get all of the fields within it?

yes, you have to     map again over each of the 'questions' to get all of the fields within it

```
const BallotForm = ({ title, questions }) => (
      <div className='ballot-form-page'>
        <div className='ballot-form'>
          <div className='ballot-title'>{title}</div>
          {
            questions.map((singleQue) => {
              return (<>
                <span>{singleQue.title}</span>
                <form>
                  <span>{singleQue.option.join('')}</span>
                  <input type='checkbox'></input>
                </form>
              </>)
            })
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
```

Comment: so that solves getting multiple ballots and showing all the options as one long option with a single checkbox, how would I go about mapping through the options and putting them in their own <span> with individual check boxes? Seems like I should break this into individual components I am going to get into gross nested maps if that's even possible.